# Sorting an array of objects of elements by an attribute of elements

Tags: ios, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have a class. Lets call this class `MyObject`.

`MyObject` has a property called `item`.

If I create an instance of `MyObject`, `instanceOfObject.item` is a `NSMetadataItem`.

`NSMetadataItem`s have an attribute called `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`.

I have an array of `MyObjects` and I want to sort that array by the attribute `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`.

I have tried

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey
                                                               ascending:YES];

[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

but this obviously crashes because `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey` is not a key of `array`. Like I said, `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey` is an attribute of `instanceOfObject.item`.

Is there a way to do this using `NSSortDescriptors`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I use this approach to sort an array of custom objects by a specified `NSString` property:

```
//Sort the list alphabetically by propertyName
NSArray* sortedArray;
sortedArray = [startingArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString* first = [(WSCustomObject*)a propertyName];
    NSString* second = [(WSCustomObject*)b propertyName];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

You just need to make sure you `#import` the custom class header where you are making this call.  You can also compare other data types using slight modifications to this approach.  If you have a specific data type in mind other than NSString let me know what it is and I can help you modify this one (or I probably already have an example of it floating around I can show you).

Comment: I guess I will have to use this method instead of NSSortDescriptors. THANKS!

Comment: The alternative would be to have your class define its own comparison method, and use `sortUsingSelector:` instead. But this solution requires no extra methods, just the class's header file to know the properties. Also, blocks rule.